# Chrome refuses to ask save password pop up if one password is already saved for same website

Tags: google-chrome

For my website, while login chrome do not show "save password" pop up if one password is already saved for same website but for different user.

Is there any form element I do want to insert so that it can show pop up each new user login.

This is working fine in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: depending on the method you are using to authenticate, the answer will be different. depending on how your site is programmed, it may sometimes not be possible. Can you include some screenshots of the popup, or explain more about the type of authentication your site is using?

Comment: Pop up means chrome's default remember password pop up.f I clear all saved password and login with credentials then it showing pop up of remember password and if I save that password with that username .after i logout and try to login with another credentials (Different usename and password) then it do not ask to to remember password pop up.it want to show that each new user login if that password not saved which is normal behavior.If I removed saved username and password from setting of chrome and try to log in with 2nd credentials then it showing pop up to save password.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424195/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-from-saving-passwords-in-asp-net-mvc